# college edu email addresses validation with swift/firebase

Tags: swift, email-validation

So I am stuck with only allowing .edu college emails on my app. I already have it set as accepting any email but I want to change it to only accept .edu emails. Anyone have a function/code that could show me on how to do this? I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You can validate the email in Swift using Regular Expressions.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if an email address ends in ".edu" like this:

```
let endsInEdu = email.hasSuffix(".edu")
```

Note that the email address may not be valid even if this returns true.